# Dependent yup validation: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') error

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

The following is a snippet of a Yup validation schema which is called by a Formik form:

```
// Yup field validation
      const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        member_type: Yup.string().required('*Member type is required'),
    
        forename: Yup.string()
          .required('*Forename is required')
          .max(35, 'Forename can be a maximum of 35 characters'),
    
        surname: Yup.string()
          .required('*Surname is required')
          .max(35, 'Surname can be a maximum of 35 characters'),
    
        dementia: Yup.string().when(['member_type'], {
          is: (member_type) => member_type.includes('Standard Member'),
          then: Yup.string().required('*Dementia information is required'),
        }),
    
        carer_relationship: Yup.string().when(['member_type'], {
          is: (member_type) => member_type.includes('Carer'),
          then: Yup.string().required('*Carer relationship is required'),
        }),
    
        cared_for_name: Yup.string()
          .when(['member_type'], {
            is: (member_type) => member_type.includes('Carer'),
            then: Yup.string().required('*Cared for name is required'),
          })
          .max(35, 'Cared For Name can be a maximum of 35 characters'),
    
        cared_for_medical_conditions: Yup.string().when(['member_type'], {
          is: (member_type) => member_type.includes('Carer'),
          then: Yup.string().required(
            '*Cared for medical condition details are required'
          ),
        poa_held: Yup.string().when(['member_type'], {
          is: (member_type) => member_type !== '' && member_type.includes('Carer'),
          then: Yup.string().required('*POA held is a required field'),
          }),

        poa_link: Yup.string().when(['poa_held'], {
          is: (poa_held) => poa_held === 'Yes',
          then: Yup.string().required(
            '*A link to a photo of the front page of the POA form required'
          ),
        }),
```

Many of the validations are dependent on the value selected from a drop-down in the first field, `member_type`, for example, the `carer_relationship` field only becomes mandatory if the `member_type` includes the string `Carer`.  Some are always mandatory, e.g. `forename`.

If a `member_type` is selected, then the form's submit button is pressed, all the validations occur as expected highlighting mandatory fields.  However, I have two issues I cannot explain:

1. If no `member_type` is selected then the form's submit button is pressed, then no validation errors trigger at all.  However, the `member_type` field itself is set to `required`, as are many other fields such as `forename`.
2. If no `member type` is selected, but data is entered in another field (e.g. as soon as a single character is entered in the `forename` field), then the console throws an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')`

This error relates to the 'poa_link' field.  If I comment out the validation logic associated with the `poa_link` field, the error is then thrown for another field which uses similar logic to `poa_link`, e.g. the `cared_for_medical_conditions` field.  And so on: commenting out validations that throw an error just results in another field then throwing an error when the same test is performed.

The error works its way up from the bottom: as I comment out validations, starting at the last field in the list, it keeps moving up, going through all the fields that include the line of code:

`is: (member_type) => member_type.includes`

Can anyone help me with these two errors, I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the issues might be.

Comment: Did you set initialValues for your form fields? Especially for `member_type`...

Comment: Yes, they are set to ''

Comment: How about writing as optional chaining? Like: `member_type?.includes`